# multiprocessing breaks in interactive mode

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I have the following code

```
from multiprocessing import Process, Queue
from queue import Empty
from time import sleep

def f(q):
    n = 100000000
    while n != 100000000 // 2:
        n -= 1
    q.put("the awkening!")
    print("my work here is done")

def main():
    q = Queue()
    p = Process(target=f, args=(q,))
    p.start()
    while True:
        try:
            print(q.get(block=False))
            raise systemexit
        except Empty:
            print("i found nothing :(")
            sleep(2)
    p.join()
```

If I add

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
     main()
```

To the end then use `python script_name.py` to run it, everything works fine. However, if I just run the scirpt using `python -i script_name.py` then run `main()` Python complains:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Python34\lib\multiprocessing\spawn.py", line 98, in spawn_main
    exitcode = _main(fd)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\multiprocessing\spawn.py", line 108, in _main
    self = pickle.load(from_parent)
AttributeError: Can't get attribute 'f' on <module '__main__' (built-in)>
```

The error comes from the child process, the main process runs fine.

This is not a big deal, but I wonder why this happens, also it would be nice if it works in interactive mode

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The [multiprocessing documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html) discusses this:

> Note
>
> Functionality within this package requires that the __main__ module be
>   importable by the children. This is covered in Programming guidelines
>   however it is worth pointing out here. This means that some examples,
>   such as the multiprocessing.Pool examples will not work in the
>   interactive interpreter.

My understanding is that `__main__` is defined very differently in the context of an interactive session (as it is associated with the shell, not the file that is running).