# multiprocessing package in interactive Python

Tags: python, multiprocessing, interactive

I have the following code test.py:

```
#multiprocessing in the interactive Python 

import time
from multiprocessing import Process, Pipe

def MyProcess(a):

    while(1):
       time.sleep(1)
       a.send("tic")    

if __name__ == "__main__":

    a, b = Pipe() 

    p = Process(target=MyProcess, args=(a,))
    p.start()

    while(1):
       msg=b.recv()
       print(msg)
```

It works fine if I execute it in the DOS shell "python test.py"
But it doesn't work if I use "Execute File" from IEP (Pyzo).

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\pyzo2014a_64b\lib\multiprocessing\spawn.py", line 106, in spawn_main
    exitcode = _main(fd)
  File "C:\pyzo2014a_64b\lib\multiprocessing\spawn.py", line 116, in _main
    self = pickle.load(from_parent)
AttributeError: Can't get attribute 'MyProcess' on <module '__main__' (built-in)>
```

I found that this is a documented 'issue'. Please check the answer of the link below.

[multiprocessing breaks in interactive mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24466804/multiprocessing-breaks-in-interactive-mode)

Does it mean that I should not use multiprocessing package from the interactive Python? Does it mean I can not create a process from the IPython console?
Any clarification on this will be highly appreciated

Answer (score 9):

Correct, you can't use `multiprocessing` from the interpreter… primarily because `pickle` doesn't know how to serialize interactive functions.  However, if you use a `multiprocessing` fork, called `pathos.multiprocessing`, you can do what you want from the interpreter.  This works because `pathos.multiprocessing` uses `dill`, and `dill` knows how to serialize functions (and other objects) that are defined in the interpreter.

```
>>> from pathos.multiprocessing import ProcessingPool as Pool
>>> 
>>> p = Pool(4)
>>> def squared(x):
...   return x**2
... 
>>> def pow(x,y):
...   return x**y
... 
>>> a = range(10)
>>> b = range(10,0,-1)
>>> 
>>> p.map(squared, a)
[0, 1, 4, 9, 16, 25, 36, 49, 64, 81]
>>> res = p.amap(pow, a, b)
>>> print "asynchronous, and with multiple inputs!"
asynchronous, and with multiple inputs!
>>> res.get()
[0, 1, 256, 2187, 4096, 3125, 1296, 343, 64, 9]
```

Get `pathos` here: https://github.com/uqfoundation

Comment: A new `pathos` release is imminent. The existing stable release is quite old, and predates `pip`, however does install trivially with `setuptools`.

Comment: Thank you Mike, 
I'll take pathos a look and will report.