# function is evaluated only when it is called from apply but not when it is called from apply_async

Tags: python, multithreading, python-multiprocessing

I've read [process-or-pool-for-what-i-am-doing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18176178/python-multiprocessing-process-or-pool-for-what-i-am-doing) and [when-to-use-apply-apply-async-or-map](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8533318/python-multiprocessing-pool-when-to-use-apply-apply-async-or-map) and I was hoping that I understand differences between `apply` and `apply_async`. But I have this code which returns desired output only when `apply` is used and is very short when `apply_async` is used:

```
#!/bin/env python
import multiprocessing
import time
import os

semaphore = multiprocessing.Semaphore(1)
# semaphore = multiprocessing.Manager().Semaphore(1)

def producer(num, len, output):
    time.sleep(1)
    element = "PROCESS: %d PID: %d, PPID: %d, QSIZE: %d" % (num, os.getpid(), os.getppid(), output.qsize())
    semaphore.acquire()
    print "PID: %s WRITE -> %s" % (os.getpid(), element)
    if (num == len - 1):
        print "PID: %d WRITE -> Everything was written inside queue, no more apply_async calling, just reading!" % os.getpid()
    output.put(element)
    semaphore.release()
    time.sleep(1)

def consumer(output):
    while True:
      try:
        print "PID: %d READ  <- %s" % (os.getpid(), output.get())
        break
      except:
        print "PID: %d READ  <- NOTHING IN BUFFER" % os.getpid()
        # pass
      time.sleep(1)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    """
    MULTIPLE PRODUCERS AND MULTIPLE CONSUMERS
    """
    output    = multiprocessing.Manager().Queue()
    pool      = multiprocessing.Pool(4)
    lst       = range(40)

    print "Calling apply*!"
    for i in lst:
        pool.apply_async(producer, (i, len(lst), output))
    print "Do not wait until apply* finishes!"

    for i in lst:
        # RETURNS OUTPUT
        # pool.apply(consumer, (output,))

        # DOES NOT RETURN OUTPUT
        pool.apply_async(consumer, (output,))
```

Output when `pool.apply` is used:

```
Calling apply*!
Do not wait until apply* finishes!
PID: 18348 WRITE -> PROCESS: 1 PID: 18348, PPID: 18341, QSIZE: 0
PID: 18346 WRITE -> PROCESS: 0 PID: 18346, PPID: 18341, QSIZE: 1
PID: 18349 WRITE -> PROCESS: 2 PID: 18349, PPID: 18341, QSIZE: 2
PID: 18347 WRITE -> PROCESS: 3 PID: 18347, PPID: 18341, QSIZE: 3
PID: 18346 WRITE -> PROCESS: 4 PID: 18346, PPID: 18341, QSIZE: 4
PID: 18348 WRITE -> PROCESS: 5 PID: 18348, PPID: 18341, QSIZE: 5
PID: 18349 WRITE -> PROCESS: 6 PID: 18349, PPID: 18341, QSIZE: 6
PID: 18347 WRITE -> PROCESS: 7 PID: 18347, PPID: 18341, QSIZE: 7
...
```

Output when `pool.apply_async` is used:

```
Calling apply*!
Do not wait until apply* finishes!
```

Seems like `producer` is evaluated only when it is called from `apply` but not when it is called from `apply_async`. Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is evaluated in either case, however it's done in another process. The difference is that `apply` is blocking while `apply_async` is not. In your code, you sent the work off to another process and then never collected it back to the main process.

Note that `apply` returns a value, while `apply_async` returns a result object.  You have to call `get` on the result object to get the result.  Here's a distilled example:

```
>>> import multiprocessing
>>> import math
>>> 
>>> p = multiprocessing.Pool() 
>>> p.apply(math.sin, (.5,))
0.479425538604203
>>> result = p.apply_async(math.sin, (.5,))
>>> result 
<multiprocessing.pool.ApplyResult object at 0x103edc350>
>>> result.get()
0.479425538604203
>>>
```

If you are doing a for loop over an `apply` or `apply_async`, you might want to think about using a `map` or `map_async`.

```
>>> p.map(math.sin, range(5))
[0.0, 0.8414709848078965, 0.9092974268256817, 0.1411200080598672, -0.7568024953079282]
>>> result = p.map_async(math.sin, range(5))
>>> result.get()
[0.0, 0.8414709848078965, 0.9092974268256817, 0.1411200080598672, -0.7568024953079282]
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I'm aware of map* functions but the main problem with using them is that they can't handle (easy way) multiple arguments. May I ask what happens to processes when I did not call `result.get()` are they somehow cleaned or what?

Comment: @WakanTanka: No, if you don't call `get`, the jobs in the other processes finish, and wait in a queue.  They are only cleared when you `close` or `terminate` the other processes.  If you want a `map` that takes multiple arguments check out my fork of `multiprocessing` (called `pathos.multiprocessing`) -- see: http://stackoverflow.com/a/28001397/2379433. It also utilizes much better serialization than the standard library version.