# How to initialize a Python multiprocessing Process whose target takes no args?

Tags: python, python-3.x, process, multiprocessing, args

rough code:

```
from multiprocessing import Process

def getPAprofilesPages():
    #do stuff here

def getPBprofilesPages():       
    #do stuff here

P1 = Process(target = getPAprofilesPages, args = [] )
P2 = Process(target = getPBprofilesPages, args = [] )
```

Notice that the functions take no arguments.
I've tried to set args equal to None, (), (,) and [] as seen above, as well as completely omit it from the initialization.
In any event, I get the same error when trying to run `P1.start()` or `P2.start()` in the interpreter:

```
>>> Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\******\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\multiprocessing\spawn.py", line 105, in spawn_main
    exitcode = _main(fd)
  File "C:\Users\******\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\multiprocessing\spawn.py", line 115, in _main
    self = reduction.pickle.load(from_parent)
AttributeError: Can't get attribute 'getPAprofilesPages' on <module '__main__' (built-in)>
```

Comment: maybe create function with argument and simply don't use this argument in function `def getPAprofilesPages(arg):`. OR maybe problem is in different place.

Comment: On Linux Mint it works without arguments. I can even use `Process(target=getPAprofilesPages)`. And it works directly in Python shell too. As I know some systems maybe need `if __name__ == '__main__':` to work correctly.

Comment: I tried it on Windows with and without ```__name__ == '__main__'``` both times I get the same error as @Alexander

Comment: That's interesting to know. __name__ is definitely "__main__", as I'm executing the script directly. Will try it on a Linux system and get back to you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following code works fine in a script

```
def main():
    ...
    all your other code goes here
    ... 
    from multiprocessing import Process
    P1 = Process(target = getPAprofilesPages )
    P2 = Process(target = getPBprofilesPages )
    P1.start()
    P2.start()

def getPAprofilesPages():
    #do stuff here
    pass

def getPBprofilesPages():
    #do stuff here
    pass

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

However, you say you are running it in the interpreter, and that is where your problem lies with the fact that you can't use [multiprocessing package in interactive Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27932987/multiprocessing-package-in-interactive-python).

I know this wasn't the answer you were looking for, but it explains your error. You can read more in that link about a workaround.

Comment: This throws no errors, but it leads to my *entire program* getting executed from the start...
I should note that the block of code in my original post is only part of a larger program that starts with taking in two inputs from the user. When I do

Comment: @Alexander I'm confused about your issue then. Can you revise your question with more information?

Comment: Sure, I just hit "Add Comment" prematurely. Here is my new problem in more detail:

This throws no errors, but it leads to my *entire script* getting executed from the start...
I should note that the block of code in my original post is only part of a larger program that starts with taking in two inputs from the user. 
When I add that IF clause above the processes' initialization and start, the script gets executed with no errors, but, again when the P1.start() is reached, it starts the script from the beginning, rather than only executing the "targets" assigned.

Comment: Ahh okay, I understand your issue. Is the rest of your code in functions or is it just in the script without being in a function?

Comment: It's just in the script. No functions, other than the two defined specifically to act as "targets" for the processes I want to initialize.
One more time, here is what happens:
The script starts with requesting two inputs from the user and then performs some actions on said inputs. The two processes I then initialize are meant to perform further actions on the data acquired so far.
However, when the program gets to the P1.start() part of the code, it just executes the ENTIRE script form the beginning, requesting two inputs even tho that part of the script was ALREADY executed.

Comment: I understand. You need to have all the rest of your code in a function like ```main()``` that I created in this answer. It's updated so that if you add the rest of your code where it says ```...
    all your other code goes here
    ... ``` your whole program should only execute once. Your issue is having all your code not contained in a function

Comment: Having all your code free floating in the script means that each child process is calling that function AND then continuing to execute the rest of the script again. There is no way around this other than putting the rest of the code under a function so that each child process ONLY executes the code in the function and not the rest of the file again. If you need more help, we can set up a chat to continue discussing this.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/201050/discussion-between-c-lewis-and-alexander).

Comment: Thank you, that seemed to do the trick and the Process now successfully initializes and executes!
However, as with any such case, new problems have arisen. Let's move to chat as you suggested.